# How to implement monkey patch in C++?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to implement monkey patching in C++?
Or any other similar approach to that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Not portably so, and due to the dangers for larger projects you better have good reason.

**The Preprocessor** is probably the best candidate, due to it's ignorance of the language itself. It can be used to rename attributes, methods and other symbol names - but the replacement is global at least for a single #include or sequence of code.

I've used that before to beat "library diamonds" into submission - Library A and B both importing an OS library S, but in different ways so that some symbols of S would be identically named but different. (namespaces were out of the question, for they'd have much more far-reaching consequences).

Similary, you can replace symbol names with compatible-but-superior classes.
e.g. in VC, `#import` generates an import library that uses `_bstr_t` as type adapter. In one project I've successfully replaced these _bstr_t uses with a compatible-enough class that interoperated better with other code, just be `#define`'ing `_bstr_t` as my replacement class for the `#import`.

**Patching the Virtual Method Table** - either replacing the entire VMT or individual methods - is somethign else I've come across. It requires good understanding of how your compiler implements VMTs. I wouldn't do that in a real life project, because it depends on  compiler internals, and you don't get any warning when thigns have changed. It's a fun exercise to learn about the implementation details of C++, though.  One application would be switching at runtime from an initializer/loader stub to a full - or even data-dependent - implementation.

**Generating code on the fly** is common in certain scenarios, such as forwarding/filtering COM Interface calls or mapping OS Window Handles to library objects. I'm not sure if this is still "monkey-patching", as it isn't really toying with the language itself.

Comment: As for depending on compiler internals, you can get a warning when things change--just build the assertions you need into your unit tests.  This has worked well for me in practice (not with vtable patching, but in other cases where I was tempted to write code which depended on e.g. a particular STL implementation aspect).

Answer (score 7):

To add to other answers, consider that any function exposed through a shared object or DLL (depending on platform) can be overridden at run-time.  Linux provides the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable, which can specify a shared object to load after all others, which can be used to override arbitrary function definitions.  It's actually about the best way to provide a "mock object" for unit-testing purposes, since it is not really invasive.  However, unlike other forms of monkey-patching, be aware that a change like this is global.  You can't specify one particular call to be different, without impacting other calls.

Answer (score 6):

Considering the "guerilla third-party library use" aspect of monkey-patching, C++ offers a number of facilities:

- `const_cast` lets you work around zealous `const` declarations.
- `#define private public` prior to header inclusion lets you access private members.
- subclassing and `use Parent::protected_field` lets you access protected members.
- you can redefine a number of things at link time.

If the third party content you're working around is provided already compiled, though, most of the things feasible in dynamic languages isn't as easy, and often isn't possible at all.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose it depends what you want to do. If you've already linked your program, you're gonna have a hard time replacing anything (short of actually changing the instructions in memory, which might be a stretch as well). However, before this happens, there are options. If you have a dynamically linked program, you can alter the way the linker operates (e.g. LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable) and have it link something else than the intended library.

Have a look at valgrind for example, which replaces (among alot of other magic stuff it's dealing with) the standard memory allocation mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

As [monkey patching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) refers to dynamically changing code, I can't imagine how this could be implemented in C++...

Comment: Is there a specific word for the less-dynamic half of monkey-patching? Stuff like const_cast, access control redefinition and RTTI abuse?