# Is it possible to add a member to `string` that gives the `int` location of the last `char` put into it?

Tags: c++

The one annoyance I have with the `std::string` class is that the only ways (that I could figure out after reading cplusplus.com's info about it) to get the location of the last character in the string is `(stringVariable.length() - 1)` or `stringVariable.rfind(stringVariable.back())`. It'd be nice if I could just do `stringVariable.last()`. This is for a function I wrote in a personal project that needs to reference this number of a user's input string.

Some ideas I had were creating a struct that is just a `string` and has the `last()` function as a member function, or a class that copies the `string` class and adds that member. With a struct, I'm not sure how (or if it's possible) to make it so I can make the variable assigned to the type automatically reference the `string` in it so that I don't need to make a constant member call. I'm taking the second C++ class in school right now, but we haven't touched on C++ classes yet.

I tried reading some guides and answers here about classes, and they don't look all that different from structs, but the more complex stuff in either case was Greek to me. I only learned how to use a struct as a holder for multiple variable types; like the `name` string and `id` int for a person,  or something like that. I learned from the guides I can put functions in them, and define operator behavior too, but when I tried to define operator behavior for the `string` struct I made, I couldn't get it to work.

Based on the example I read, I tried:

```cpp
str &operator=(const str &ing)
{
    s = ing.s;
    return s;
}
```

But when I tried to test it by using `=` to copy a `str` variable to a `string` variable I could `cout`, it errors that `str` can't be converted to `string`, so I tried a few adjustments, and after getting errors about the `&` and such, I ended up with:

```cpp
string operator=(str ing)
{
    return ing.s;
}
```

Which gets the same error. Here's the full struct test program I'm using:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct str
{
    string s;

    string operator=(str ing)
    {
        return ing.s;
    }

    int last()
    {
        return s.length() - 1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    str ing {"Hello World!"};
    string i = ing;
    cout << i;

    return 0;
}
```

If I could get the `=` assignment to work, I'd try to get `<<` and such to work with `str`, too.

If that doesn't turn out to be possible, my fallback is just using a function like:

```cpp
int last(string str)
{
    return str.length() - 1;
}
```

Edit: For More Info

I was asked many times in the comments what my actual need is for this. In truth it’s just that it annoys me that it doesn’t have that member function. I’m surprised it wasn’t implemented long ago.

Thanks to the commenters I was able to come up with the diabolical workaround of overloading an operator to make a `string` able to subtract a function to output the result of a `string` being input to the function. I used `-` because I was thinking script notation: `stringVariable -l` or `stringVariable -last`. Then I can also just use `#define` to remove the need for the operator, making it `stringVariable last()` (“last()” instead of “last” because aesthetic).

Another option I figured out was reversing positions and using `#define` to make it `last stringVariable`, or `#define in -` to make it `last in stringVariable`. Although the simplest version of the operator function for this by far is just defining a negative `string` as the `int` output directly. Not that any of that is really better than just using the function normally, but I enjoyed learning about those features of C++.

The single answerer also consolidated much of the commenters advice and brought it to the next level to give me a more elegant version of the idea I had to create my own class with a `string` that could do all the `string` stuff and the extra member. However taking the advice of reexamining my needs I think perhaps ‘string’ isn’t the only option I have for a user input container. I definitely need the `int` output made by `stringVariable.size() - 1` with whatever `char` array I use (since it’s used in mathematical equations), but maybe a vector or something else could do that already?

I was briefly told about vectors in my previous class, but we weren’t allowed to use them. Since this is for a simulated environment I’m doing on my own (that I might use for the basis of a game some day) I can use anything I want though. I also decided to pull an allnighter last night and just started reading about containers at random on cplusplus.com.

So I’m wondering if perhaps a `list` or `deque` could work too. I wasn’t really taught about anything other than `string` and hardcoded arrays (yet) though. I use the `string` to store the user’s input to simplify the process of avoiding unforeseeable crashing/errors that come from bad user inputs, then just translate the `string`s to whatever I need with various functions I've written.

Comment: sooo `stringVariable.end()`? `get the location of the last character in the string` What do you mean by "location"?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use iterators? And can you explain why `str.length() - 1` (or slightly shorter, `str.size() - 1`) isn't acceptable? This question gets kinda fuzzy in the middle; I'm not sure how the first two paragraphs and the last code sample relate to anything in the middle. "Location" of the last character is pretty fuzzy too; the index of the last character? An iterator pointing to the last character? A raw pointer that dereferences to the last character?

Comment: For the assignment what about a conversion operator: https://onlinegdb.com/c36q2ThqU

Comment: To answer the question from your title, [no, there is no sane way to monkey-patch an existing type in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1584907/364696).

Comment: A free function is the normal way to extend classes in C++: `last_index(str)`. (Fun fact, this exact function is `thing.lastIndex` in Kotlin, so there is precedent for that name.)

Comment: @ShadowRanger, I can offer that a well-named function for this can sometimes reduce the chance of running into off-by-one errors, "one of the hard problems in computer science".

Comment: You could make an [extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57081233/4641116).  But please don't do that, because your coworkers will have a hard time disposing of your body.

Comment: Beware [XY problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You have already concluded that the "fix" to your situation is to make changes to `std::string` instead of making them to how you use your string. This might rule out better solutions for your real goal.

Comment: There is no way to add member functions to a standard class (in the sense of the class being specified by the standard) in C++.    Not only is a non-member function the normal way to extend functionality of a class in C++, it is a *recommended practice*  (e.g. by authors such as Scott Meyers in his "Effective C++" series) over adding member functions.

Comment: You still haven't really explained _why_ it's so important to have this function.  It kinda goes against all paradigms in C++ (and C, for that matter) dealing with strings.  You're always going to see "length - 1" in code that accesses the index of the last character in the string.  Why hide this in an extra layer?  It just makes your program harder to follow when read by any experienced developer.  Not only that, you've introduced an implicit typecast by assuming the index is of type `int`.

Comment: And each time you call `last`, you need to ensure the string is not empty... Unless you are in a domain where you really do a lot of processing on strings, I would simply use indexing (`str[str.length() - 1]`) or iterator (`*--str.end()`). If you still want utilities functions them put free functions in a namespace : `namespace strutils { char last(const std::string &); }`

Answer (score 0):

> creating a struct that is just a `string` and has the `last()` function as a member function

That will work just fine, if you don't mind implementing the interfaces needed to convert between `std::string` <-> `str`.

Also, be aware that `std::string` indexes use `std::string::size_type`, which is not `int`.  `size_type` is an *unsigned* type, typically `std::size_t`.  `std::string` defines an `npos` constant to indicate "no index", that is what your `last()` function should return if the `std::string` is empty, eg:

```cpp
std::string::size_type last_index() const
{
    return !s.empty() ? s.size() - 1 : std::string::npos;
}
```

But, if you really want to have `last()` return an `int` (ie, your `std::string` will never exceed 2147483647 characters):

```cpp
int last_index() const
{
    return static_cast<int>(s.size()) - 1;
}
```

> With a struct, I'm not sure how (or if it's possible) to make it so I can make the variable assigned to the type automatically reference the `string` in it so that I don’t need to make a constant member call.

In short, no.

> Based on the example I read, I tried:
>
> ```cpp
> str &operator=(const str &ing)
> {
>     s = ing.s;
>     return s;
> }
> ```

It needs to return a reference to the `str` object that is being assigned to, not the `std::string` member that was actually modified, eg:

```cpp
str& operator=(const str &rhs)
{
    s = rhs.s;
    return *this;
}
```

> But when I tried to test it by using `=` to copy a `str` variable to a `string` variable I could `cout`, it errors that `str` can't be converted to `string`

Correct, it can't by default.  You need to define a conversion operator for that purpose, eg:

```cpp
operator std::string() const
{
    return s;
}
```

> If I could get the `=` assignment to work, I'd try to get `<<` and such to work with `str`, too.

Yes, you should, eg:

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const str &rhs)
{
    return out << rhs.s;
}
```

> If that doesn't turn out to be possible, my fallback is just using a function

That is a good idea, eg:

```cpp
std::string::size_type last_index(const std::string &s)
{
    return !s.empty() ? s.size() - 1 : std::string::npos;
}
```

Or:

```cpp
int last_index(const str::string &s)
{
    return static_cast<int>(s.size()) - 1;
}
```

> Here's the full struct test program I'm using

Try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class str
{
private:
    string s;

public:
    str() = default;
    str(const string &s) : s(s) {}

    str& operator=(const str &rhs)
    {
        s = rhs.s;
        return *this;
    }

    operator string() const
    {
        return s;
    }

    string::size_type last_index() const
    {
        return !s.empty() ? s.size() - 1 : string::npos;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const str &rhs)
    {
        return out << rhs.s;
    }
};

string::size_type last_index(const string &s)
{
    return !s.empty() ? s.size() - 1 : string::npos;
}

int main()
{
    str ing {"Hello World!"};
    cout << ing << endl;
    cout << ing.last_index() << endl;

    string i = ing;
    cout << i << endl;
    cout << last_index(i) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```